# I written php code in html form, how to call that(php and html) code in ajax success function without page reload

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

In form I written a php code if data exist in database EDIT button
display,if data does not exist in database it will display ADD button
below shown my code(form),this code how to call in ajax success
function

[image]

**form**

```
<?php
                                                if (empty($s_tin_number[0]) || empty($s_tin_number)) {
                                                    ?>
                                                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">
                                                        <div class="profile-edit col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">Add</div>
                                                    </a>
                                                <?php } else { ?>
                                                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">
                                                        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 profile-edit"> <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Edit</div>
                                                    </a>                                          
                                                <?php } ?>
```

**script**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#data_form').on('submit', function (e) {
            var form_data = $(this).serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/Profile_cntrl/supplier_company_insert_update',
                data: form_data,
                success: function (data)
                {
                    $('#cname').text($("#company_name").val());
//                    here i want to check the in database field empty or not(above i written php code how to call in success function
                },
                error: function ()
                {
                    alert('failed');
                }
            });
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: make an another Ajax call with param

Comment: how sir i am not getting..above php code how to call in ajax success

Comment: you can add code in an if() which will execute  on param check  and then add another call to same page in success with param.So this time only if is executed after sucsess. OR you need to change structure of your code.  try this if not work then let me know will guide you

Answer (score 0):

So you're returning the whole HTML markup for **Add** and **Edit** buttons. You can just append it wherever you need to.

Your success function will then be;

```
function (data) {
    $('#button_container').html( data );
}
```

**#button_container** will be the container ID where you want to put Add/Edit button.

Another solution is to simplify your PHP code to send back only the button label and then you can use logic on it in JS

PHP:

```
if (empty($s_tin_number[0]) || empty($s_tin_number)) {
    echo 'add';   
} else {
    echo "edit";
}
die();
```

Success function in AJAX:

```
function( data ) {
    if ( data == 'add' ) {
        // do something awesome for add button here
    } else {
        // your edit button code here
    }
}
```

Comment: @amar Which one? The `$('#button_container').html( data );` or the second solution?

Comment: if ( data == 'add' ) {
        // do something awesome for add button here
         $('#button_container').html( data );
    } else {
        // your edit button code here
         $('#button_containerr').html( data );
    }

Comment: Did you change your PHP code accordingly? and did you change the success function in your AJAX?

Comment: Test and debug the code. Since I can't access your working environment i.e. website I can't write the exact code for you.